# Why a class needs to be whitelisted in corda? What is the major difference between a whitelisted class and a normal class?

Tags: kotlin, corda, whitelist

Is whitelisting a class be sufficient to use the datatypes such as Date?

How we can say that a particular class needs to be serialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corda doesn't allow all class to be deserialized by default because there are known exploits and vulnerabilities around it. Hence, Corda only allows whitelisted classes to be deserialized. Classes can be simply whitelisted using `@CordaSerializable` annotation on top of your class.

By Default, Corda has whitelisted some classes for you [check here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/6b149f8aad302279aa342cdd0c54ff3273704ec4/serialization/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/serialization/internal/DefaultWhitelist.kt#L15). If the class you want to whitelist is not present here then you'll have to whitelist it yourself.

Comment: Correct. Note that if you want to serialise a third-party class to which you can't add the `@CordaSerializable` annotation, you can add the class to the node's serialization whitelist instead.